# Arrays and Collection with Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I want to achieve something like this in groovy:

```
int arr[] = new int[2];
ArrayList<arr> al = new ArrayList<arr>();
for (3times) {
   ar[0] = Value coming from db;
   ar[1] = Value coming from db;
   al.add(arr);
}
println al(1)(2)
```

Comment: It seems unclear what You're asking about.

Comment: in array, i m getting 1st record , then adding it to List(Collection),then for 2nd record and 3rd and on.... and finally want to fetch values from that LIST ....

Comment: That is some oddly specific pseudocode. You use java generics but use them wrongly.

Comment: I want to achieve it in GROOVY

Comment: have you looked at http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections

Comment: @cfrick Got to know where I was running wrong after babsai's Answer . I was missing creation of array inside for loop .... BTW thnx 4 ur immediate help Opal, nablex and cfrick .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
def arr = []
def al = []
for (i in 1..3) {   
    arr = []
    arr[0] = 1 //some value
    arr[1] = 2 //some value
    al.add(arr)
}

println al[0][1]
```

​

Comment: ohhh.. Actually I was missing creation of array(arr in ur example) object inside for loop... Kiddie mistake ..